# Normalizing Database to 1NF

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Does anyone have code/ideas for changing a table formatted like

```
Bldg____Meter1___Meter2___Meter3
Bldg1___1________2________3_____
Bldg2___4________5________6_____
```

to

```
Bldg____Meter
Bldg1___1____
Bldg1___2____
Bldg1___3____
Bldg2___4____
Bldg2___5____
Bldg2___6____
```

This is normalizing to 1NF right?

Also anyway to do this through VBA or SQL is fine, just looking for any ideas.

Comment: Have you looked at CrossTab queries in Access?

Comment: No I haven't seen those before but I'm looking at them right now. I didn't even know what to look up for them, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO newTab (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter1 FROM oldTab
INSERT INTO newTab (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter2 FROM oldTab
INSERT INTO newTab (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter3 FROM oldTab
```

Comment: I keep getting syntax error in FROM clause, can I name newTab whatever I want or does it need to be an existing table? What if I want to create a new table?

Comment: @hypetech you need to create your `newTab` first.

Comment: Also, in Access, these need to be run as 3 separate statements. i.e. only one of these lines can be in the query window at a time.

Comment: Do I have to create 3 queries then, or can I write some VBA to do them all at once?

Comment: Ok so I split this into three SQL statements and ran them in VBA, however only the first statement is actually inserting. I'm still not getting the other column's data. This is the code I'm using `Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblBldgElectricMtrs (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter1 FROM qryElMetersSplit;", False
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblBldgElectricMtrs (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter2 FROM qryElMetersSplit;", False
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblBldgElectricMtrs (Bldg, Meter) SELECT Bldg, Meter3 FROM qryElMetersSplit;", False

End Sub`

Comment: Ok, the sql statements work at the same time if you have them run one after another in a vba statement. I just had to change things about the table I made, making the bldg not unique and making the meter required, and then I got exactly the table I was looking for. Thanks guys!